# statsmodel armax: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset

Tags: pandas, statsmodels

I am trying to use a simple ARMAX model to predict a time series (GDP) based on another time series (covar). I keep getting: ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.

The GDP and covar time series are monthly data points from 201101 to 201505. I would like to predict GDP over all 12 months of 2014 just as a test.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the error:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:466: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  "Check mle_retvals", ConvergenceWarning)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-31da1f1fb1a0> in <module>()
     20 armax = sm.tsa.ARMA(y, order=(3, 3), exog=u).fit()
     21 
---> 22 pred = armax.predict(start,end, u2, dynamic=True)
     23 #print ('Predicted Price (ARMAX): {}' .format(pred))

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\wrapper.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     90         results = object.__getattribute__(self, '_results')
     91         data = results.model.data
---> 92         return data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how)
     93 
     94     argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py in predict(self, start, end, exog, dynamic)
   1439 
   1440     def predict(self, start=None, end=None, exog=None, dynamic=False):
-> 1441         return self.model.predict(self.params, start, end, exog, dynamic)
   1442     predict.__doc__ = _arma_results_predict
   1443 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py in predict(self, params, start, end, exog, dynamic)
    730             # also return error estimates and confidence intervals
    731             # but how? len(endog) is not tot_obs
--> 732             out_of_sample += end - start + 1
    733             return _arma_predict_out_of_sample(params, out_of_sample, resid,
    734                                                k_ar, self.k_ma, self.k_trend,

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__sub__ (pandas\tslib.c:17055)()

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__add__ (pandas\tslib.c:16554)()

ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.
```

Here is my code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
test_data=pd.read_excel("C:/.../Correlations.xlsx", sheetname="Sheet2", encoding='utf-8')
test_data["Month"]=pd.to_datetime(test_data["Month"],format='%Y%m')
test_data=test_data.set_index(['Month'])
y=test_data["GDP"]
u=test_data["covar"]

start=pd.to_datetime("201401",format='%Y%m')
end=pd.to_datetime("201412",format='%Y%m')

u2=test_data[pd.to_datetime("201401",format='%Y%m'):pd.to_datetime("201412",format='%Y%m')]["covar"]
armax = sm.tsa.ARMA(y, order=(3, 3), exog=u).fit()

pred = armax.predict(start,end, u2, dynamic=True) 
#print ('Predicted Price (ARMAX): {}' .format(pred))
```

Comment: It looks like pandas `Timestamp` is not supported as a type for `end` in predict. See https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2587 and associated mailing list thread for workarounds until this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the statsmodels documents, `ARMAResults.predict()` has four parameters, in which the third parameter `exog`, aslo known as independent variables, is not necessary to be given.

In your case, since the prediction time interval is from Jan 2014 to Dec 2014, it is part of your original data, so it is type of in-sample prediction. The `exog` parameter can be `None`. Consequently, your code can be modified as follow:

```
pred = armax.predict(start,end,dynamic=True)
```

However, you may insist to indicating the exog. In this situation, you can use in my opinion `pandas.DataFrame.loc[]` to slice a patial data from `test_data['covar']`.